# How to sort custom class objects iside of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, swap

I am wondering how to sort an array that contains objects of a custom class. I am trying to apply different sorting algorithms but in the swapping something goes wrong.

Here is my Code:

```
class RaceCar
{
private:
    char* _brand;
    char* _model;
    double _price;
    int _horse_power;

public:

    //Other code
    RaceCar(const RaceCar& rc):_price(rc._price), _horse_power(rc._horse_power)
    {
         _brand = new char[strlen(rc._brand)+1];
         strcpy(_brand, rc._brand);
         _model = new char[strlen(rc._model)+1];
         strcpy(_model,rc._model);
    }

    RaceCar& operator=(const RaceCar& rc)
    {
        if(this != &rc)
        {
            delete _brand;
            delete _model;
            _brand = new char[strlen(rc._brand)+1];
            strcpy(_brand, rc._brand);
            _model = new char[strlen(rc._model)+1];
            strcpy(_model, rc._model);

            _price = rc._price;
            _horse_power = rc._horse_power;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    bool operator<(const RaceCar& rc)
    {
        return (this->_price/this->_horse_power) > (rc._price/rc._horse_power);
    }

    //Other code
};
```

And this is the class that contains an array of RaceCars. I am trying to implement SortCars() method that orders the RaceCar objects inside the array of cars:

```
class RaceCarGarage
{
private:
    RaceCar* _cars;
    int _max_cars;
    int _curr_occupied;
public:
    RaceCarGarage():_cars(NULL), _max_cars(0),_curr_occupied(0){}
    RaceCarGarage(const RaceCar& car, int max_cars)
    :_max_cars(max_cars), _curr_occupied(0)
    {
        _cars = new RaceCar[_max_cars];
    }
    ~RaceCarGarage()
    {
        delete _cars;
    }

    void AddCar(const RaceCar& car)
    {
        if(_curr_occupied < _max_cars)
        {
            _cars[_curr_occupied] = car;
            _curr_occupied += 1;
        }
    }

    void DisplayCars()
    {
        if(_curr_occupied > 0)
        {
            for(int i=0 ; i<_curr_occupied ; i++)
            {
                cout<<(i+1)<<". ";
                (_cars+i)->Display();
            }
        }
    }

    void SortCars()
    {
        if(_curr_occupied > 1)
        {
            for(int i=0 ; i<_curr_occupied ; i++)
            {
                for(int j = i+1 ; j<_curr_occupied ; j++)
                {
                    if(_cars[j]<_cars[i])
                    {
                        RaceCar buffer = _cars[i];
                     _cars[i] = _cars[j];
                     _cars[j] = buffer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Change the `char *`s to `std::string`s and `RaceCar *` to `std::vector<RaceCar>` and get rid of the destructor and `operator=`.

Comment: Well, the idea is to use char* and RaceCar* . But  your comment is not related with the question in any way.

Comment: My comment is promoting more idiomatic C++. Your classes are misusing the pointers and replacing them with classes designed for these purposes relieves you from having to worry about correct management.

Comment: I guess that this is the right approach but I am preparing for a school exam which doesn't include the vector and string objects. We have to manage the memory ourselves.

Comment: So, if you really want to use `new[]`, use `delete[]` to avoid memory leak.

Comment: If you can't use `std::string` and `std::vector`, then create a simplified `MyString` and `MyVector`.

Comment: Have you also defined a copy constructor for `RaceCar`?

Comment: @Jarod42: Using `delete` instead of `delete[]` is not a memory leak, but undefined behaviour, and I've seen actual crashes because of that.

Comment: @celtschk I haven't defined a copy constructor. Just operator= .

Comment: @user2128702 Then you're violating the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). Define a proper copy-ctor.

Comment: @user2128702: Then define one. If you don't, you're almost guaranteed to get troubles. Always remember the rule of three (rule of 5 in C++11): If you have any of copy assignment, copy constructor or destructor (in C++11, add move constructor/move assignment), you almost always need all three.

Comment: @celtschk But it is not mandatory. I don't need it in my context. I just need to swap two of the elements in an array based on the comparison with operator<.

Comment: So how do you swap two elements without using the copy constructor? Unless using C++11's move constructor (which I guess you didn't implement either), I don't know a way to do that.

Comment: like that: `void swap(RaceCar&lhs, RaceCar&rhs){RaceCar tmp; tmp = lhs; lhs = rhs; rhs = tmp;}`... As `RaceCar` has a default constructor in OP's code.

Comment: @celtschk Do you know what? I just added the copy constructor to the RaceCar class and it worked. I will update my question now. But, can you explain why it works after my update?

Comment: Ah, OK, that of course works ... it's just needlessly inefficient.

Comment: @celtschk But, why was the copy consturctor needed? I am not using the RaceCar(carObject) constructor anywhere! Is it happening implicitly somehow?

Comment: After your update, I see your swap does *not* look like the one in the comment: it instead does `Racecar buffer = _cars[i];` which explicitly uses the copy constructor (despite the `=` sign).

Comment: So, what you are saying is that RaceCar buffer = _cars[i] is equal to RaceCar buffer(_cars[i]), right?

Comment: Exactly. Initialization always uses a constructor, even if using the `=` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the swapping is that you use the traditional way to do:

```
temp = a        // operator= 
a = b           // operator=
b = temp;       // operator=
```

However, if you write:

```
RaceCar temp = a;   // Copy constructor gets called (see comment on standard) 
a = b;          // operator=
b = temp;       // operator=
```

The default copy constructor, just copies member by member, so just copies your pointer.  So at the end, your temp and your will try to delete twice the same object pointed to.

**Remark on assignment initializer :**
For a type T, a statement in form `T a = b;` is an initializer.
The ISO standard C++ in section 12.6.1 point 1 explains "*a single assignment-expression can be specified as an initializer using the = form of initialization. Either direct-initialization semantics or copy-initialization semantics apply;*"

Comment: There's nothing compiler dependent on the interpretation of `Racecar temp = a` (unless you include compilers which don't implement C++, that is). `Racecar temp = a` never ever will use the assignment operator. Indeed, you can make the assignment operator inaccessible, and that line will still compile fine.

Comment: @celtschk I fully agree with you in practice, however, I once met a guy who pointed out C++ Standard, section 12.6.1 point 1:  "a single assignment-expression can be specified as an initializer using the = form of initialization. Either direct-initialization semantics or copy-initialization semantics apply".  So even if I have never seen a compiler going for assignment, I'd like to mention the possibility.

Comment: Well, I don't have the standard here to look up the context, but an "assignment expression" is a grammatical thing (basically, anything of the form `a = b` in source code), while the behaviour is specified in the sentence "Either direct-initialization semantics or copy-initialization semantics apply" which means that either the constructor corresponding to the rhs type is called (direct-initialization semantics), or the rhs object is first implicitly converted to the type of the initialized object, and then the copy constructor is called on the temporary object (copy-initialization semantics).

Comment: I'm not language lawyer, but the sentence seems to mean that for `T a=b;` the compiler is free to choose between `T a; a=b;`  or `T a(b)`.  I don't know why they've written that ! Stroustrup's original book clearly stated a copy constructor for this case.  And any reasonable optimizer would anyway end up going for the copy consturctor to avoid an unnecessary intermediary object.  So you are right in practice, but the standard is the standard.

Comment: What I wrote is what I understand that the standard says. The important point is that an "assignment expression" is not the same as the call of an assignment operator, but a concept purely at the parsing stage. And the semantics (which describes what the compiler is allowed to do when it sees such code) does not mention assignment at all, but only direct-initialization and copy-initialization. So I'm quite sure that calling the assignment operator in that case would violate the standard.

Comment: I don't know if it would violate the standard, but I see your point.  So I've edited the answer to overemphasize the initialisation point we all agree on, an put the sentence of the standard for completeness, so that readers can interpret it on their own.